# Chrome Displays Irregular Random String Instead Of Image

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome

I am tring to code a HttpEntity responsebody that I could get Images according to their ids. However I couldn't display image on chrome. I tested in different java code:

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(url);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    OUtils.copy(fin, out);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fin);

    response.flushBuffer();
```

And

```
    InputStream IS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(url));
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(IS);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);

    try (InputStream inputStream = IS) {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
        imageIS.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Image>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

It works fine at Explorer However,Instead of Image, At chrome I get like:

```
‰PNG

���
IHDR����h���“Çµa��€�IDATxÚt¼…wYÖö›¦éy§‡»{:2IfŒ™™eK¶˜ÁZ’eË$ƒÌÌL±“8Æ˜™™c;àd¾ï/¹»TIfî»î]ëY•R¹ttª¢Ú¿óì}îñH4>™. 0b¨LìÀ.‘ÊÁGó¢(\YHa&Æˆ²âã+´eY©²)“/ª.Ìo©ª†­6^Ì$Æğ’D1i2©F¡ÈT©ò5é%Úì¢¬œìMZ¼*I§ŒÊ8<   ‹%f2e,–„Á€8.?A(ãrÉÁA^6–ÎX[ÆÉØ˜èë›£NÙ9Ğß?ñ¬­½®<¿9[ıª$u¤&e¹«xg¢m{~pgse}}}vn¹¿o¸º¬6?³  =?/-7G“›—‘WœUXš]\–_^^TYV\UVRY^TQZPR˜_R]˜Ÿ™Ÿ›—¯Éƒwåeäg§åd©3Ó”)I²ÄøX¹Œ+1ù14–Á1XB:SÌæÈùB¥P’(U&+“5‰éš¤ôŒ”¬¬mNJv~š¶4+«¶ ³µ<çeUv_]îPcşxSşT[ş|gşbWÁrwÑZ_Éæëòíáò¡Ò¡â½‘Ò½Ñâİ‘¢½±¼ı±âÃ©òÃéªƒ©êıÉŠ½‰Òİ±â‘’íáâí‘Âa^çoôf¯¾Ê\~?×$™¨búr_¥ûu$z¶ÈœŠ˜Ö™Ñæò`s¦‡)ÁÑïbíeÏq“à£ålZ¢T ì,ÉXì-İ_h?ß{{¹üáfóÃ»Ã.î>Ü€>}xóéıÅÇw§wo?Ş|¼Ù½»Ş¹»Şº»İşx»÷éíá¿ß}|toy»ww»õñzõÓ›¥OWsŸ.Æ>ö<ê}·×ıvóÙ›…òó‰Œ½áú3ÊR~¥™µÒ![}¿Ò¥Z•°Ñ!Ym¦¯Ô…¯7â6ÚHk­ È•¿•†ùÊ ¹âÀ±l·á,û—É–µó–i1Û¨:Ó*3îQ[§»ŒjİG²{Ò-Ÿ+í›„Õã*–IÍ$ŸˆÍ6ÍÆ›dŒµ‘ÆáFa†9á¥Qúud½*È ™¢ßB~ÒF{òŒ¡j¥éÃÁ:¢~Ş¨8Ü8/Ü2ï˜Nö×°£Óœ™<E‘¨V&'Å§$)’àÿQ\b’2-E•š‘’†H÷×Y‚"&NÊ™11®€Êñ),.‰Á¥09dÊĞ9ğ§şÄ#2ØÑLÇEøã|½#ıü¢ƒ‰Á¡¤ÈHVYDåÄ±bâx¹@-+c¤²™2V/ŠSÄJe|‘˜#dñ¡M>*–Î³q<‘2&ùÇÄ)bäq|©„#‚/3|“ci,xº9Ñv¶ğŒCg$ÜX  _"ÆÉÅŠx™*AJT$%)’A   ²D¥D.‘ÀÇ    ¨L&D
€Nâıı£@°O   Ã1ğDDİeÆĞùˆX1B$âŠ‹•
‰ÚWÅ%‚”RU\lœˆ+`ñ Yx/\24B‹ˆ"‡ECpQAap7ğş8¿0/¯0PwwPˆ›[ ³s€“(ÈÅ^†zzGÃ"È8<›Dı|7(,>‰) ÒØ‘DF(SâÃ*Øá#jânëªAôöYüÛWIºÕÿ~)ÿ¿ü7á?UyŞ•Ú]ç¿WıñVñÃ¥øÛÁ½}ö·kÌoißÍP¾%şq”ø§âŸFI?Ò~güe‚ñ÷  ÆÏ£”ÿÑƒûç³ Ÿ«ıîg{>V8>Ø<ˆ²ÒÃ[èÌÓmôÄ®z©AOJ¢ÖÓ½àêõˆŒ&ƒ ¦C‰f#‰f£ñ&#rÃá¸ÇıÂ'½ü'=œ']ÌÇ”‡mÄ‡Í„G•ÁFÅşJ~kúWOäïst£©íyšÇu  ímMÌ»fÅmKâMkâÛå»zñM%ï¢”r¦Åª}7âœùV“Tã×Ñ˜—xıöPLc ¦ÚSæƒ-ö6.õ3.óÇV›Ô‡™ÔáLËBŒ3}Œå®¦,;Óps#?¬ÆÈÇëÅxbÜÜLœõ°O@ö¬!líõõ±Ff†~–Q.†‚ ƒ{ÿPáˆüh*HDe©c¥�•²ÌàJ¶BªàR2ãÅ5E…mµ
õ¥%9‰   )±±IBA²*YñJmbbAZZq–¶(3+75-M¯–Êâcbd”ÉÑhb:]L#Kô86KÁåÄIx_/Ok€Š=ãnfB    È'TWrÒÓ3âêÒ•/
‡ª’–ŸçoµlÍ½ŞİXÙX¨,ôõ
T•Væ¦çækr³Ó²s49¹™yÅ9Å¥y¥@”ò’êŠÒDÅ•e…åyÅy9…yYK€+è6+-[›”õ*2)'B>Üä9¤ÅPéğRÆQ
eV ¤&j²R²²“³r’3ŠÒµ5y¹­eù/jò{
†šÆÛ‹æ—.u•¯t—¯÷Ul
VnUîÕLÔNÖNVƒ&*A‡ãG“eG“å'3u'³Ç3
GÓõ‡ÓpZåşxù4Z¶;\²=X´õºp§7gıe: e¾Y<]Ë+§äF¼Hõo’¹Vğ´”§Êpa€×ß‘à*ó‘C<F’4¦*=a¢½|wæÙÙöÀûÓùwoÖßßî~üpzw÷æÃİg¨|D r‚BåN@…
ü   ôA•o·?İlÜ]/}¼œıx>úñäõ‡£ş÷{}·[Ï¯–ªÎ¦µ½’êJKÔzwã¥r³G½Õ›¸Ñ­Ú~)Üì¤­·á7ŸEm¶×špËÕ~óenÓÅ®¯3_©íÛe6bË¶i:ÁXˆMÁçR,*¹-b«.•ı`šëH¦ç@šÓ+µcGœucŒi=Ï¬‚aR@2¨dE`3qÆ ¬-Î$/[iXK4l&´R�!mTıvº^ÓàÓ nĞJ3l V0e8“üpó¬H‡t’¯†•Îg§Éd©rUò¨¨eğNPËÕÉñ*‰ Jª*-Y™URDß±LDjj<2ˆÂŠ¢²£iÌh*›Dº@ÌEã'ŠÆÀSiÄèPœŸo˜·'ÎÇ‡C "¤qå\   àA.”T qˆì€“¯DA>ˆÁ…�Š„BÆCr¾X!N@À9[�B`¦{´(,   tÈËF¸QB?\�21N­–'ÁV%M€ï¼”'„ã’hôÈhrh8„{@ !J0¼¤á"6�¸4œt~,C�p±bÅl*R® ¥”Æ¥@ñó…1l>4×-ƒ(áxRh
¸ÿ*€`WW”((Tàeˆ‡ÎÏÎ¨°ˆäë¸—ËÁñNZLí“…¯gFŸ•Qo¸Z[ØŸêÉÿ§*äßÅÎsLï2_'ıãü»+Éwg±ßqïí°¿A Bÿv–úÍù   ê' ?Œ1~¥ıÏå¯ƒ¤¿õşö<üoõ¿yİOr~(²Öc™ë‘Ìi–z‡Ç*ŸG¹k™Ÿ‹÷Æë
'¥šO¤[gZOfXO¦[M¤š«GäOúEº¸¿wĞï·’ï7D=¨xXò¸ÀO/Çëa±ßÃÆàßğ–ØFûñöo²ƒnË¹ïëÄï›U·mÉ7­I·Í 7uÒ7üóbÊiVøÚk]æ°À³�¨0/"ŒÚBŒêü
«|J½1E^Øb?,@¥2È¸.Ä¢&Ô¬$«ñ1’¹a&a–†¾fz>fş@@…ÉS=_SC3#oSCSwD†®Æú.X=Øº›b|Ìõ‚-
È®¢Ã{(N`ƒ
å......
```

Comment: Did you set the correct content-type?

Comment: yes, I suppose. @Produces("image/*"). It works fine except chrome.

Comment: You should inspect the headers of the response in the chrome debugging tools. If there is no content-type headers than it might explain the gibberish you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are sending the right http headers in your response.

e.g for a png you should send a header of 'content-type' with the value 'image/png'.

Comment: @Produces("image/*")  and also adde response.setContentType("image/png");